# Python: Assign Percentage to Every Element in a List

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have an algorithm that is going to buy stocks based on Simple Moving Average, but I am stuck on trying to assign a percentage to a dynamic list.

For example, the algorithm is allowed to buy four stocks one it's the first week, so a list is created with four elements: `["apple", "google", "tesla", "AMD"]`.

The next week it buys six stocks and creates a list with six stocks: `["apple", "google", "tesla", "AMD", "intel", "qualcomm"]`.

What I want to do is dynamically assign a percentage to each element in the list that will equal 100%.

So, in the first week, Apple would be assigned 50%, Google at 25%, Tesla at 15%, and AMD at 10%.

In the second week, Apple may be assigned 50%, Google at 25%, Tesla at 16.5%, AMD at 5%, intel at 2.5%, and qualcomm at 1%.

In the final result, I want to give the algorithm a list of numbers and assign each element a percentage starting high and ending low but still equalling 100%.

Here I my current code:

```
from quantopian.pipeline.factors import VWAP
from quantopian.algorithm import attach_pipeline, pipeline_output
from quantopian.pipeline import Pipeline
from quantopian.pipeline.data.builtin import USEquityPricing
from quantopian.pipeline.factors import AverageDollarVolume
from quantopian.pipeline.filters.morningstar import Q1500US
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math

def initialize(context):
    """
    Called once at the start of the algorithm.
    """   

    # Sets default slippage and commission fees to simulate real trading.
    set_commission(commission.PerShare(cost=0.0075, min_trade_cost=1.00))
    set_slippage(slippage.VolumeShareSlippage(volume_limit=0.025, price_impact=0.1))
    set_asset_restrictions(security_lists.restrict_leveraged_etfs)

    # Creates a function that runs at the beginning of each week.
    schedule_function(start_of_week, date_rules.week_start(), time_rules.market_open(hours=1))

    # Rebalance every day, 1 hour after market open.
    schedule_function(my_rebalance, date_rules.week_end(), time_rules.market_open(hours=1))

    # Record tracking variables at the end of each day.
    schedule_function(my_record_vars, date_rules.every_day(), time_rules.market_close())

    #Creates a function that runs at the beginning of everyday.
    schedule_function(start_of_day, date_rules.every_day(), time_rules.market_open(hours=1.5))

    # Create our dynamic stock selector.
    pipe = Pipeline()
    attach_pipeline(pipe, name='my_pipeline')

    # Construct Volume Factor.
    vwap = VWAP(inputs=[USEquityPricing.close, USEquityPricing.volume], window_length=14)

    prices_under_5 = (vwap < 5)

    pipe.set_screen(prices_under_5)

    context.df_long = pd.DataFrame(None, columns=list("ABC"))
    context.df_short = pd.DataFrame(None, columns=list("ABC"))
    context.long_list = []
    context.short_list = []

def start_of_week(context, data):
    """
    Called at the begining of every week before market open.
    """
    context.df_long = pd.DataFrame(None, columns=list("AB"))
    context.df_short = pd.DataFrame(None, columns=list("AB"))
    context.long_list = []
    context.short_list = []

    context.output = pipeline_output('my_pipeline')

    # These are the securities that we are interested in trading each day.
    context.security_list = context.output.sort_index(axis=0, ascending=True, kind='quicksort')
    context.security_list = context.security_list.index


    for security in context.security_list:

        # Gets Simple Moving Average for 7 days and 100 days
        price_hist_8 = data.history(security, 'price', 7, '1d')
        mavg8 = price_hist_8.mean()
        price_hist_14 = data.history(security, 'price', 100, '1d')
        mavg14 = price_hist_14.mean()
        current_vol = data.current(securrity, "volume")


        if mavg8 > mavg14:
            #Calculate percent increase of volume
            current_vol = data.current(security, "volume")
            hist_vol = data.history(security, "volume", 10, "1d")
            difference_increase_vol = current_vol - hist_vol
            percent_increase_vol = (difference_increase_vol / hist_vol) * 100
            percent_increase_vol = percent_increase_vol[0]

            if perecent_increase_vol >= 0:
                context.df_long_tbd = pd.DataFrame([[security, mavg8]], columns=list("AB"))
                frames = [context.df_long, context.df_long_tbd]
                context.df_long = pd.concat(frames)





# Sorts all of the stocks in the "long" Data Frame from steepest incline in simple moving average over 8 days. The "final_long_list" contains all of the top stocks' names.
result_long = context.df_long.sort_values(by=["B", "A"], ascending=False)
context.long_final_list = result_long["A"]

# Total amout of stocks that the algorithim is allowed to buy will be determined on total portfolial value.
# If the total portfolial value is $100,000, the algorithim is only allowed to look at 
port_val = context.portfolio.portfolio_value
allowed_to_purchase = round(sqrt(port_val)/10)

for stock in context.long_final_list[:allowed_to_purchase]:
    if data.can_trade(stock):
```

Let's say that "allowed_to_purchase" equals 10. Now, I want to assign each stock in the top ten of my context.long_final_list a percentage, starting high and ending low, equal to 100%.

Is there a simple solution or a built-in function? "context.long_final_list" is a pandas data frame, is there a function that pandas has?

Comment: Better make use of dictionary

Comment: Sounds like you want a dictionary, not a list...

Comment: Can it be done in a pandas data frame?

Comment: @MalachiBazar Well... yes.

Comment: @erip How would I go about doing that?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: @Prune With all due respect, I believe my question was a ligament one. I gave a sinario of my problem and clearly described what I wanted to happen. I was hoping there was an easy formula or built-in python function that would solve my problem. Apparently not. :(

Comment: @MalachiBazar you don't even show your attempts, you don't even ask if there's a 'easy solution' or a built-in (which is off topic also without your attempt[s]), all you are doing right now is posting your homework-like question in hopes that someone will solve it for you. Which is off topic on this site.

Comment: @MooingRawr Thank you for the tip. I have edited the post accordingly, and I assure you that this is not a homework assignment for a Junior in high school.

Comment: Much better now.  I've retracted my close vote and down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! If I add all of the stocks values into a total single term and then divide the total term by the value of each stock.

For example in my Pandas Data Frame context.long_final_list:

```
A       B
Apple   150
Google  600
AMD     12


#Counter
n = 0

#For every stock price in my pandas data frame add it's value to n. 
#n will equal the total price of all the stocks.
for stock in context.long_final_list["B"]:
    n = n+stock

#Now, to assign percentages to divide the stock by n.

Apple_percent = apple/n
```